# AssertArrayEquals on the result of Method Invoke

Tags: java, arrays, methods, junit

So, I'm trying to implement a function that will essentially compare all the fields of two objects that are the same class, using an Introspector and PropertyDescriptor.  Where I've run into issues is arrays.

I've used the PropertyDescriptor to get the Get methods for each field as Methods, and one of these fields is an array.  I know that it is a byte[], but I want the method to be able to handle any kind of array.  Unfortunately, the return type for Method.invoke(Object o...) is Object, which cannot be plugged into any of the AssertArrayEquals() methods.

Casting does not seem to work, and my understanding of generics is apparently not up to snuff.  How would you compare these two arrays?

```
Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
if(method.getReturnType().isArray()){
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(method.invoke(obj1), method.invoke(obj2));
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/).

Assume the following test class:

```
public class TestObject {

    private byte[] content;

    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

You can compare the content field like this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

[...]

PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor("content", TestObject.class);
Method readMethod = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();

assertThat(readMethod.invoke(testObject1), equalTo(readMethod.invoke(testObject2)));
```

This will work with array and non-array fields, Hamcrest does the check for you.

Comment: Furthermore, have a look at https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest.  We built this specifically for comparing entire object graphs in an easy to use way